# Como instalar o Composer globalmente no linux?

Tags: linux, composer

Geralmente, quando instalamos o Composer, costumo fazer assim:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Ele baixa um arquivo chamado `composer.phar`. Mas daí eu tenho que ficar colocando o caminho da pasta toda hora que eu vou executar.

Por exemplo:

```
~/downloads/composer.phar
```

Eu gostaria de fazer simplesmente isso na linha de comando:

```
 composer self-update && composer update
```

Como posso fazer isso no Linux?

Comment: Faz sentindo essa pergunta? [Mesmo a documentação já deixando explicito como fazer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally)?

Comment: A documentação está em inglês, não vejo problemas com minha pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Aliases

Um alias poderia resolver

`vi ~/.bashrc`

adicione

`alias nome_do_alias=comando`

exemplo

`alias composer=/a/pasta/onde/estah/conposer.phar`

O recurso do alias varia de acordo com a distribuição Linux, mas no geral é similar ao exemplo acima.

## Symbolic link

Outro modo ainda mais simples é criar um symbolic link

`ln -s /local/do/arquivo/composer.phar composer`

Comment: Boa alternativa ;)

Comment: Cara massa, vou usar esta!

Comment: Realmente, assim é melhor. Se tiver que atualizar com `self-update`, não teria problemas de permissão (aconteceu isso no nosso servidor semi-dedicado, não tenho acesso ao sudo)

Answer (score 8):

A solução para isso é apenas mover o arquivo baixado para a pasta `/usr/local/bin`.

Vamos lá.

1) Primeiro baixe o arquivo do composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

2) Creio que, antes de mover é apenas necessário dar permissão de execução:

```
 sudo chmod +x composer.phar
```

3) E depois, simplesmente mova-o:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Fonte**: [Install Composer on Linux and Mac OS X](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/composer.html)

Se você não tiver o `curl` instalado, você pode rodar o comando:

```
 sudo apt-get install curl
```

Ou então, usar uma dessas opções, no lugar do primeiro passo:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

Ou

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
```

Comment: `wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar` vai baixar na pasta do usuário, não?

Comment: Sim, mas aí ele move depois de baixar. Como eu disse, é uma substituição do primeiro passo.

Comment: Ah é verdade, viajei, uso Debian, e lá "não suporta" `sudo`, fazemos o uso de `su` o que nos leva a "pasta de usuário" do root :)

Comment: Consegui instalar tranquilamente o composer, valeu :D

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente, baixe o instalador do composer em qualquer pasta:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Em seguida, use o comando `mv` para mover o arquivo do composer para a pasta onde o linux reconhece os comandos:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Aí você pode utilizar no terminal

```
composer install ...
```