# Como instalar dependências pelo Composer, mas ignorando o require-dev?

Tags: composer

Aqui na empresa onde trabalho utilizamos o `git` para o versionamento da aplicação. Todas elas utilizam o Composer para instalar as dependências.

Pelo fato de ser a abordagem mais correta, removendo o `vendor` gerado pelo `Composer` do repositório. Ou seja, quando alguém fizer o `git clone` ou o `git pull` deverá atualizar as dependências via Composer.

Porém surgiu uma questão: Quando estamos desenvolvendo algumas dependências são instaladas como `require-dev`. Mas quando atualizamos o sistema em produção, como utilizamos o git para fazer o `git pull`,  precisamos também rodar o `composer update` em produção.

Porém, quando é em produção, **não quero que seja incluída** a dependência de desenvolvimento (require-dev).

Como posso rodar o `composer install` ou `composer update` ignorando as dependências que eu incluí no `require-dev`?

Exemplo:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle" : "6.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "phplegends/pt-br-validator" : "2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
```

A dependência do `require-dev` não pode ser instalada em produção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a documentação https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md deve-se usar o parâmetro `--no-dev`, exemplo de comandos:

- Se o composer estiver global:

  ```
  composer install --no-dev
  composer update --no-dev
  ```
- Se não estiver global:

  ```
  php composer.phar install --no-dev
  php composer.phar update --no-dev
  ```

Se o seu servidor ou hospedagem não tiver a opção de SSH ou composer disponível você pode rodar os comandos em sua máquina e subir o projeto atualizado depois.

> **Nota:** Se quiser instalar o composer globalmente recomento ler isto [Como instalar o Composer globalmente no linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118467/3635)