# O Npm roda sem estar instalado o Node?

Tags: node.js, npm

Uso aqui na empresa um Linux Ubuntu, e instalei o **vue-cli** pelo **npm** versão 3.5.2, instalando a pasta **node-modules** normalmente com todas as dependências dentro, mas, quando executei um `node -v` ele imprime a seguinte mensagem no terminal **O programa 'node' não está instalado no momento. Você pode instalá-lo digitando:
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy**. Mas o npm não é um gerenciador de pacotes do Node, não necessitaria do mesmo para poder executar?

Comment: Se você rodar `npm show node version` também ocorre erro?

Comment: @Pagotti Olha que interessante cara, rodou normal, a versão 10.9.0. Não conhecia este comando não. Valeu man.

Comment: Esse comando mostra a versão do pacote do node que o npm enxerga no repositório, mas não quer dizer que essa versão que está instalada no seu ambiente. Talvez tenha que rodar a instalação do node novamente.

Comment: Certo entnedi man. Se eu instalar o node novamente corro riscos de perder algo?

Comment: Eu não vou dizer que não tem riscos. Sempre tem pq tem configurações globais, mas tudo depende do seu ambiente.

Comment: Certo,  mais uma vez obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem muitas possibilidades para isto, a mais provavel do meu ponto de vista é que, você instalou o `Node.js`, ou seja já tem sim ele instalado, mas ele não esta GLOBAL (nas variaveis de ambiente `PATH` ou como "atalho" dos comandos).

Mas é provavel que você tenha coloca o comando `npm` como global, semelhante a situação do `composer` em Linux:

- [Como instalar o Composer globalmente no linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118467/3635)

Conforme [estas respostas no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20031849/1518921) e sendo Ubuntu, pode experimentar o comando:

```
dpkg-query -L nodejs
```

> Não tenho linux para testar no momento

É provável que o caminho seja `/usr/bin/node` ou `/usr/bin/nodejs`, mas até então é só uma hipótese. Pode ser qualquer coisa até então, você instalou, desinstalou coisas, pode ser simplesmente uma versão com bug, pode ter instalado múltiplas versões do nodejs e depois removeu uma delas mantendo a outra, ainda sim durante a remoção a variavel `PATH` já havia sido sobrescrita.

Não vou ficar muito com hipóteses, porque parece um erro local. **Ainda sim** uma coisa que preciso ressaltar que não entendo o porque esta usando `nodejs-legacy` no Ubuntu, a não ser realmente que esteja querendo algum suporte para aplicações mais antigas.

Agora se o teu Ubuntu for antigo ai sim deve estar faltando coisas, recomendo que siga os passos em:

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/OLDER_DISTROS.md

Comment: Opa Guilherme obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.